# Struts2 getText dynamic value

Tags: jsp, struts2, gettext

I'm trying to pass the current year to the struts2 getText method:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Calendar" %>

<p>
    <s:text name="app.footer" />
    <s:text name="%{getText('app.footer2', Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))}" />
</p>
```

Global properties:

```
app.footer                      Copyright &copy; 2018 All rights reserved
app.footer2                     Copyright &copy; {0} All rights reserved
```

The first one works, the second one doesn't. Why?

Comment: Access to static methods/fields is disabled by default due to security reasons.

Comment: Ok, a possible solution would be a method in my base action which returns the current year, but i don't really like it. Do you have a hint for another solution?

Comment: You can use a method that is not static.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `session.put("currentYear", Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))` then `<s:text name="%{getText('app.footer2', #session.currentYear)}" />`.